# rename keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i want to rename the keys of a dictionary are which are ints, and i need them to be ints with leading zeros's so that they sort correctly.

for example my keys are like:

```
'1','101','11'
```

and i need them to be:

```
'001','101','011'
```

this is what im doing now, but i know there is a better way

```
tmpDict = {}
  for oldKey in aDict:
 tmpDict['%04d'%int(oldKey)] = aDict[oldKey]
newDict = tmpDict
```

Comment: Im confused. Why doesn't a numerical sort work to sort the keys? Dictionaries guarantee no sort order for keys so changing the key.

Comment: Why not convert them to numbers? ( you can even display them as binary if needed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way. If you want to pull the entries from the dict in a sorted manner then you need to sort upon extraction.

```
for k in sorted(D, key=int):
  print '%s: %r' % (k, D[k])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort with whatever key you want.

So, for example: `sorted(mydict, key=int)`

Answer (score 0):

```
aDict = dict((('%04d' % oldKey, oldValue) \
             for (oldKey, oldValue) in aDict.iteritems()))
```

...or `%03d` if you need three digits as in your example.